# CS50 Recovering jpg images from card.raw

Tags: c, image, jpeg, cs50, recovery

I have some issues regarding the CS50 Pset4 Recovery of jpg files problem.

My code is able to compile, however only 2 jpg files were created even though it should have created 50 jpg files. I don't see any problem with the code, but i suspect that the jpg files are not created because somehow the `fread` function reaches the EOF earlier than it should.

But I'm clueless regarding this. Any help in identifying an error would be greatly appreciated :D

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
//Only accepts 2 arguments
if (argc != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: Recover JPEG images\n");
    return 1;
}

//opens file file for reading
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (file == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file\n");
    return 2;
}

unsigned char buffer[512];

//initializing file numbering
int count = 0;
char filename[7];
FILE *img = NULL;

//reads 512 bytes each time until EOF
while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 1)
{
    //Detect the start of a JPEG file
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
    {
        //if output file was not created before, create one
        if (img == NULL)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");

            if (img == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", filename);
            }

            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
            count += 1;
        }
        //if output file was already created, close it and open a following output file
        else
        {
            fclose(img);

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", count);
            img = fopen(filename, "w");

            if (img == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open %s\n", filename);
            }

            fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    //if there is an output file open but has not reached the start of a new jpg, write into the current opened file
    else
    {
         if (img != NULL)
         {
             fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, img);
         }
    }
}
//close all files
if (img)
{
    fclose(img);
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: Your code skips every other 512 bytes because it calls `fread` twice and only uses the second one.

Comment: also: `"rb"`, `"wb"`

Comment: ...and fails to read any '%512' bytes at the end of the file.

Comment: @immibis Thanks for the advice regarding the double `fread`! I have since removed that part. Also @Antti Haapala i have changed the code to `rb` and `wb`. Sadly i'm still unable to open up any of the jpg files.

Comment: perhaps you should try printg the buffer for debuggung purposes, are you sure the file is open? your code seems to be correct so perhaps the issue is in the file read...

Comment: Looks like time to use your debugger...

Answer (score 0):

`fread` advances the file pointer hence:

```
while(fread(buffer, 512, 1, file) == 512)
{
    fread(buffer, 512, 1, file);
```

this execution actuallt reads 1024bytes but buffer holds only the second half (512bytes), which means that every loop you will skip 512bytes

```
--------------------------
|512b|512b|512b|512b|512b|
--------------------------
-skip-read-skip-read-skip-
```

is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It wasn't intentional and i have since changed the code. However i still fail to open up any jpg files...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally figured out the problem. The problem was that I assigned `char filename[7];` where i gave the number `7` because the name of each file will be `00x.jpg` which i believed uses 7 chars. However it seems that the program will only work if i input the number higher than 7, for e.g. '8' or '10'. I believe this extra char space is for the '\0' that i failed to account for. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for all those who helped :D